# No swap in survivor area

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jstat

[image: jstat -gc]
This is the result of my gc command. Why is the survivor area not swapped after Minor GC? Why didn't the old age increase at all?

Comment: Which GC? What JVM version?

Comment: @apangin G1 and jdk1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S0C`/`S0U` counters are [not used](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/96cdb50fe0bf/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1MonitoringSupport.cpp#l151) with G1 GC.

G1 has no dedicated survivor spaces and no dedicated old/young areas. Any G1 region can serve as Old, Young or Survivor. See [this article](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/part-1-introduction-g1-garbage-collector) for details.

`S1C`/`S1U` jstat counters represent the total amount of memory occupied by survivor regions; `S0C`/`S0U` are always zero.